# SSL/HTTPS website stop working after Server Changes

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql, ssl

I was running ubuntu 18.04 on Amazon LightSail and went to create server from backup Instance (Data Recovery) . Same Static IP but different servers/same files/same system,

Suddenly all HTTPS websites stop working. HTTP websites are fine.

My Server is using
Apache with MySQL
Running Ubuntu 18.04

There was no setting changes , I needed to do to recover some accidently deleted files.

Please kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now.
Lightsail disable port 443 by default

Comment: Can you explain which commands did you use? Pleace [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193192/ssl-https-website-stop-working-after-server-changes/1193222#1193222) your answer

Comment: it is under LightSail Admin UI section, Just under networking add SSL/443 and should work fine.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1193222/edit) your question, it would be easier to explain each step with an edit rather than in comment